# How to switch the horizontal screen to the vertical screen

Tags: windows-phone-8

When rotate the screen of the phone,how to make the vertical (XAML) switch to another designed horizontal(XAML), rather than automatically layout the old vertical (XAML) to the horizontal(XAML)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you currently use a `StackPanel` (or similar), and have already specified `SupportedOrientations` as `PortraitOrLandscape`, you need to design your page constnet in a `Grid` instead, and then trap the `OrientationChanged` event and write code to reposition the UI elemnts in the grid.

There is a [Quickstart Tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207002%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that shows the technique.

**EDIT**

You could change to different XAML by trapping the `OrientationChanged` event and displaying a different page using `Frame.Navigate`, but I think that would result in some duplicate code. Or, you can code your page so that you just have to move items around in the `Grid` like the MSDN exmaple code shows:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Switch the placement of the buttons based on an orientation change.
    if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.Portrait))
    {
        Grid.SetRow(buttonList, 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(buttonList, 0);
    }
    // If not in portrait, move buttonList content to visible row and column.
    else
    {
        Grid.SetRow(buttonList, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(buttonList, 1);
    }
}
```

Alternative is to navigate to a different page - so in your portrait page, you might have:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Switch to a different page based on an orientation change.
    if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Landscape) == (PageOrientation.Landscape))
    {
        // switch to landscape orientation page
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/LandscapePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
    }
}
```

Then you would have similar code in the landscape page, to detect the orientation change and navigate back to the portrait page.

Comment: But when the tow xamls are so diffrent,what should I do ?

Comment: I want to change to another new horizontal(xaml) when rotate the screen

Comment: And could you please give me an example that how to use the Frame.Navigate in the "PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged()"

Comment: Excuse me again,what should I do if I want to use the back key in the lower-left corner of the phone to end the program rather than return to the last page

Comment: Take a look here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394012(v=vs.105).aspx - if you still have trouble, perhaps post this as a new question, you'll get better response that way.